# How to decrypt POST request body in golang

Tags: go

I am getting my request body value in encrypted form as below:

`9oF0LS0aY0RGGfUEGoT%2FHSdqypxXKh7lmaTawlekrxw%3D`

But the actual value I send is:

`9oF0LS0aY0RGGfUEGoT/HSdqypxXKh7lmaTawlekrxw=`

Any suggestion How I can get correct value.

Comment: Share code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text has been [url encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Probably because it was a query parameter ?

What you can do is use the [`url.QueryUnescape`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#QueryUnescape) function to decode the value.

```
str := "9oF0LS0aY0RGGfUEGoT%2FHSdqypxXKh7lmaTawlekrxw%3D"
str, _ = url.QueryUnescape(str)
```